# Problems accessing my tablet api with PhoneGap

Tags: android, api, cordova, jquery-mobile

I need some help to make my app.

I am working on a school project where I want to be able to take pictures or access the tablet's picture gallery, as I like to have the option to save images captured with the tablet in a MySQL database.

However, I can not get this part to work. It's as if I do not have permission to connect to the tablet api.
The app (android) is built in dreamweaver using JQuery Mobile. To connect to the tablet api I want to use PhoneGap Build.
I have chosen to not to use the built-in function in DW to upload to PhoneGap, because I just think it gives more problems. Instead I just making a zip file and upload on their website.

My first question is if I have misunderstood the use of PhoneGap Build. I have read in a lot of places that you have to use Eclipse with PhoneGap, is it really necessary to activate my tablet's camera?
I would like to stick to HTML / css / JS because that's what I know best, instead of having to use Java.

This is my HTML code,

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <div data-role="content" id="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><div data-role="button" onClick="take_pic();">Take a Picture</div></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><div data-role="button" onClick="album_pic();">Select</div></div>
    </div>
    <img id="cameraImage" src="" />
</div><!-- /content -->


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="JS/camera.js"></script>
```

This is my camera.js file which I call the end of the page

```
function take_pic() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, function(ex) {
    alert("Camera Error!");
}, { quality : 30, destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

function album_pic() { 
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, function(ex) {
        alert("Camera Error!"); }, 
        { quality: 30, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    // Android Quirk: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY and 
    // Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM display the same photo album.
    sourceType: pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM });
}
```

the code for the two functions are taken from the side
[Demo App of PhoneGap APIs using jQuery Mobile](https://github.com/libbybaldwin/phonegap-api-demo-jquery-mobile)

I very much hope there is someone who can help me with what I'm doing wrong. Nothing happens when I press the 2 buttons I made and I do not really know how to test an app.

Answer (score 0):

The Phonegap Build service which are using needs certain tweaks. You cannot directly convert the www folder and upload it to the build service. I Suggest you to use the following link to learn and modify html for phonegap build service.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start

I was just trying around and modified the index files for the ones you gave.. Give it a try(even though it may not be completely working).

https://github.com/varunbhat/phonegap-test-app

Hope this helps you .. Hope you enjoy the phonegap experience.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I do not understand much of it. Or I understand some of it, but can not see how I can turn it around to help me to get my camera to work. But I found out that I should do something more than just throwing it over in PhoneGap to get it to work.
Thank you.
Morten